# Can't start Liferay6.2 Tomcat7 server in debug mode

Tags: tomcat, liferay, portlet

My liferay server is working fine except in debug mode...It just prints this in console....

```
    Jun 25, 2014 1:32:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
    INFO: 
    The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments
     was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib
    /x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib

    Jun 25, 2014 1:32:06 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]

    INFO: Deploys configuration descripter 
    Starts loading jar files
    Starts Loading portal-setup-wizard.properties,portal-ide.properties,portal-developer.properties
    ...........
    Jun 25, 2014 1:32:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
    13:32:40,161 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1][DialectDetector:71] Determine dialect for MySQL 5
    13:32:40,340 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1][DialectDetector:136] Found dialect org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

and stops printing in console here and never starts............

Comment: How long does it stay in this situation? More than ten, fifteen minutes?

Comment: More than that...Until I restart...again it will be the same

Comment: Can you start it up in non-debug mode?

Comment: yeah...it's working fine in non-debug mode....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sweta.
While starting the tomcat in debug mode, it requires a far more amount of memory than in normal starting. You can try to increase the memory that has been given to the tomcat.
Also please make sure that while you are restarting the tomcat, there is no debugging break point element. This can be checked by going into the debug mode.
Hope this helps you out.

Comment: I have increased the memory too and these are memory args in liferay server config setting...-Xmx1024m-XX:MaxPermSize=512m and i have removed all breakpoints earlier itself..still not working...

Comment: Probably it was due to 2 GB RAM, When I upgraded to 4 GB RAM there were no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it was due to 2 GB RAM, When I upgraded to 4 GB RAM there were no issues.